# DJANGO Aggregate with Foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a group by clause on a foreign key but am having a couple of issues.

The code;

```
status_applications = DevelopmentAssessment.objects.values('status').annotate(total = Count('status'))
```

The field status only returns an integer for the status value instead of the related object. Is there a way to have it return the related object so I can use the field names in the related table in a for loop?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: there is not enough information to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You basically already have an answer.

`status_applications` is a QuerySet that contains a set of related objects (statuses) you are asking for.
`status_applications[0]` would be the first, `[1]` second and so on.

To access the count of each simply do:

```
for status in status_applications:
    print status, status.total
```

If you need the whole rows of the table then simply don't use values or leave it empty:

```
applications = DevelopmentAssessment.objects.annotate(total = Count('status'))
```

or

```
applications = DevelopmentAssessment.objects.values().annotate(total = Count('status'))
```